# Connecting callback to QML Singleton Type declared in C++

Tags: c++, callback, singleton, qml, signals

I am currently refactoring my code to replace a QObject declared and instantiated in QML with one that's registered and initialized as a SingletonType. Here is what the old code used to look like:

The main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("MyPackage", 1, 0, "MyClass");
  etc.
}
```

The class .cpp:

```
Class MyClass : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  signals:
    void dataAvailable(const QString dataId);
    etc.
}
```

The main.qml:

```
import MyPackage 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
  MyClass {
    id: myClass

    onDataAvailable {
      // Do stuff here
    }
  }
}
```

And here is what the new code looks like:

The main.cpp:

```
static MyClass* myClass_ = new MyClass();
// Create singleton
static QObject *mySingleton_((QQmlEngine* engine, QJSEngine* scriptEngine) {
  Q_UNUSED(engine)
  Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

  return myClass_;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyClass>("MyPackage", 1, 0, "MyClass", mySingleton_);
  etc.
}
```

The class .cpp (unchanged):

```
Class MyClass : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  signals:
    void dataAvailable(const QString dataId);
    etc.
}
```

The main.qml:

```
import MyPackage 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
  Connections {
    target: MyClass
    onDataAvailable: {
      console.error("onDataAvailable")
    }
  }
}
```

All the previous functionality of MyClass is working just fine with this new Singleton setup. However, the onDataAvailable block is not being hit, as the console.error statement above never prints. I have confirmed that the signal is being emitted properly. I believe the issue here is with the Connections code above, which is probably wrong.

How can I use Connections correctly here? Failing that, is it possible to manually inject QML to this object (from the C++ side) to add this callback block?

Comment: I think you missed to fire (`emit`) the signal !!!

Comment: you must provide a [mcve], currently your code is irreproducible since it is incomplete.